# What are in-memory data structures in python?

Tags: python, in-memory

I was given a coding challenge in which I have to parse a text file and build **"A data structure in memory to work with."** . I then have to perform descriptive statistics on it. So far I've parsed the text and build a dictionary containing all the needed data.

I haven't used SQlite or something similar because they specifically asked for data structures and not databases.
I am not sure if dictionary is correct here. So my question is: **What are in-memory data sructures in python?** I've tried the web but couldn't get an definitive answer.

Comment: Every data structure is stored in memory...

Comment: List, dictionary are all in-memory data structures. What they could also be referring to is Linked List, Stack, Queue, etc implementations.

Comment: A dictionary is a data structure. It sounds like you have it stored in RAM which is what they mean by memory. My guess is they are saying you cannot use things like SQlite.

Comment: In your case every data structure that does not leave your Python application should count as in-memory. This includes dictionaries. An example of the opposite is an SQLite file based database. (It also offers an in-memory database. As what it would count is a matter of interpretation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An in memory data structure is one that is stored in RAM (as opposed to saved to disk or “pickled”). If you’re not using external programs that store to disk for you (like databases) and not explicitly storing to disk, you’ve created an in-memory data structure. Dicts, lists, sets, etc. are all data structures, and if you don’t save it to disk they’re in-memory data structures.